# Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: java

I'm trying to prompt the user if he/she wants to play again. I am having trouble writing the code that will prompt the user for input. I've look at my earlier coding from the semester but those were not using multiple method. So, when I try format it as the previous ones but its not work so I took it out. Can anyone help me with this?

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project         Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package hwchallenge5;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Roberto Martinez
 */
public class HwChallenge5 {
    /**
     * Method will return null if an invalid choice is given.
     * 1=rock, 2=paper, or 3=scissors.
     *
     * @param number
     * @return string type
     */
    public static String getChoice(int number) {
        String choice;
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                choice = "rock";
                break;
            case 2:
                choice = "paper";
                break;
            case 3:
                choice = "scissors";
                break;
            default:
                choice = null;
        }
        return choice;
    }

    /**
     * Method should generate a random number and then return the
     * computers choice.
     *
     * @return The computer's choice of "rock", "paper", or "scissors".
     */
    public static String computerChoice() {
        // Create a Random object.
        Random rand = new Random();

        // Generate a random number in the range of
        // 1 through 3.
        int num = rand.nextInt(3) + 1;

        // Return the computer's choice.
        return getChoice(num);
    }

    /**
     * Method should return the user's choice.
     *
     * @param keyboard
     * @return The user's choice of "rock", "paper", or "scissors".
     */
    public static String userChoice(Scanner keyboard) {
        // Ask the user for input
        System.out.print("Enter 1 - rock, 2 - paper, or 3 - scissors: ");

        int userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
        String play = getChoice(userChoice);

        // Validate the choice.
        while (play == null) {
            System.out.print("Enter 1 - rock, 2 - paper, or 3 - scissors: ");
            userChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
            play = getChoice(userChoice);
        }

        // Return the user's choice.
        return play;
    }

    /**
     * The determineWinner method returns the output based on parameters
     *
     * @param computerChoice The computer's choice.
     * @param userChoice The user's choice.
     */
    public static String determineWinner(String computerChoice, String userChoice) {
        String output;

        output = "The computer's choice was " + computerChoice + ".\n";
        output += "The user's choice was " + userChoice + ".\n\n";

        // check logic
        if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock")) {
            if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
                output += "Rock beats scissors.\nThe user wins!";
            else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
                output += "Paper beats rock.\nThe computer wins!";
            else
                output += "The game is tied!\nPlay again...";
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper")) {
            if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors"))
                output += "Scissors beats paper.\nThe computer wins!";
            else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
                output += "Paper beats rock.\nThe user wins!";
            else
                output += "The game is tied!\nPlay again...";
        } else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors")) {
            if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock"))
                output += "Rock beats scissors.\nThe computer wins!";
            else if (computerChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper"))
                output += "Scissors beats paper.\nThe user wins!";
            else
                output += "The game is tied!";

        }
        return output;
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {



  String computer = null;
  String user = null;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  char playAgain=0;

  // Play the game as long as there is a tie.
  do {

    while (user.equalsIgnoreCase(computer));
    // Get the computer's choice.
    computer = computerChoice();

    // Get the user's choice.
    user = userChoice(keyboard);

    // Determine the winner.
    String output = determineWinner(computer, user);
    System.out.println(output);

     // Ask the user if he wants to play again
    System.out.println("Do you want to play again?");
    // Prompt the user for a yes or no
    System.out.print("Enter Y for yes or N for no: ");
    String input = keyboard.nextLine();
    // Indentifys the first letter of of user's answer
     playAgain = input.charAt(0);
    // Allows the user to input upper or lower case Char as a respond


  } while(playAgain =='Y' || playAgain== 'y');


    } 
}
```

Comment: If what way does the code not work as expected?  "It's not working" doesn't really describe the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  What does "not work mean?"

Comment: I sometimes think there should be Homework Compendium, that has every possible homework assignment encountered to this day and that compendium should be shoved into every new SO user face.

Comment: the code is not asking the user if he wants to play again.

Comment: To keep playing until the user decides to quit, you could wrap an infinite loop around your `do...while` in the `main` method that prompts the user after exiting the `do...while` and breaks if they don't want to play again.

Comment: @RobertoMartinez: Well, where in the code do you ask if the user wants to play again?

Comment: Add the code you tried back so people know what issue you had

Comment: I was attempting to put it at the end of the do-while loop but it wasn't prompting the user if he wanted to play again. Therefore I deleted it.

Comment: @RobertoMartinez: Well, if you deleted the code then that would explain why it's not working.  We can't tell you what's wrong with code you won't show us.

Comment: Wow David I didn't know that. Thank you for that captain obvious!

Comment: If you want help you will have to add the code you tried to your question, then we can look at it and see what your problem is, otherwise you won't get any help

Comment: @Shadow: Thank you. I added the deleted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close, first off, you want to move your `while (user.equalsIgnoreCase(computer));` to where you have your `while(playAgain =='Y' || playAgain== 'y');` otherwise that first while will throw a `NullPointerException` and prevent your program from compiling (you could remove it entirely if you want them to be able to quit if they tie instead of having to play again).

You can then create a function to check whether the user would like to play again, something like:

```
public static boolean PlayAgain(Scanner keyboard) {
    //Ask user if they want to play again
    //return true if yes else return false
}
```

Then you can combine that function with your `do {...} while()` like so:

```
do {
    //current code
    //get user choice
    //get computer choice
    //determine winner
} while (user.equalsIgnoreCase(computer) || PlayAgain(keyboard));
```

If the first condition is `true`, the second condition is never checked, which means the function won't get called unless they either win or lose.

Comment: @RobertoMartinez No worries, if it solved your problem please accept it as the answer by clicking the tick mark